# rails current_teacher keyword not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm looking at an application that has a variable called current_teacher. I cannot seem to find where this is set. Everywhere I look the code seems to read from it but where is it set. Is this one of those things that Rails does for you. There is a mode and a table called teachers, so I'm sure this has something to do with it.

I'm very confused by statements like the following, can someone tell me how Rails does this?

```
if current_teacher.can_request_fieldtrip
```

Comment: Do you use _pry_ or _pry-rails_ ?

Comment: Could you post some code??

Comment: If your text editor supports "Find in Folder", search for `current_teacher`?

Comment: If you are using devise current_user object is accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does not support authentication by itself, however there are a lot of 'add-ons' that rails can use. These 'add-ons' are called [gems](https://rubygems.org/). This can be a little confusing because you can't actually see their code inside your project folder.

If you open a file called "Gemfile" (it should be in your project folder) you can see a list of gems that you use. Try searching their names on google, you will probably find official web page that contains it's documentation. That way can learn what they do and how to use them.

current_teacher method smells like "Devise" gem
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

I'm not sure about can_request_fieldtrip, this could be a custom method defined in Teacher model.

Comment: I took a look at Devise and yes, that's what added current_teacher. It explains it clearly in http://guides.railsgirls.com/devise/.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a controller like :

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    if current_teacher.can_request_fieldtrip
      # code
    end
  end
end
```

Here is debugging tips :

(a) put this in your **Gemfile** and do `bundle install` :

```
  `gem 'pry-rails', :group => :development`
```

(b) Put the line `binding.pry` just before the `if` statement.

(c) Start rails server using `rails s`.

(d) Hit the browser like http://localhost:3000/new

(e) Now you will be in the Pry console. Just do in the console,

```
 method(:current_teacher).source_location
```

And the above line tell you where the method has been defined.

Documentation of [`Method#source_location`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-source_location)

> Returns the Ruby source *filename* and *line number* containing this method or nil if this method was not defined in Ruby (i.e. **native**)